# Frame Resizing using AutoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout

I have an `UIView` inside which i have a `UIButton`.  I am using auto layout.  Now I want to reduce the height of the `UIView`.  How should I do it ? On reducing the height of the `UIView` , the `UIButton` inside the view should also move up at the same time.  How can i do this using Auto Layout ?

Comment: Button inside a view....

Comment: you need to call layoutIfneeded after you chnage the constraints!!! Look at this answer for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609206/setneedslayout-vs-setneedsupdateconstraints-and-layoutifneeded-vs-updateconstra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create IBOutlet for height constraint of you view and you can change value for it.Just check how to create.

[image: Creating UIVIew height constraint outlet]

[image: Outlet created]

Now use the code below to set height of you UIVIew

```
  heightConstraintOfView.constant = DYNAMIC_HEIGHT;
```

Comment: Need further help then let me know.

Comment: so after making the height of the view as dynamic can i change the frame (view.frame.height). and will a button inside this view automatically get re framed.?

Comment: dont forget to do layoutIfneeded after you change the constraints!!! @Anilsolanki

Comment: @MainakChoudhury If it has correct authorizes - yes

Comment: You cannot change the frame of view with view.frame.height .It will not effect.But if you will change height by constraint coding as I suggest then you should not fix the  UIbutton height.Make it's autolayout without fixed height.

Comment: My `UIView` frame is (0,0,560,145). Constraints are set accordingly. Now i add a `UIButton` with frame(0,130,100,15)Constraints set (No Ht constraints). So when i dynamically change the ht constraint of the `UIView` by 20. My button does not move up. @Anilsolanki