# How can I make views height depend on its content in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have got a view and some elements in it

```
let background_img_view: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    return view
}()
background_img_view.addSubview(background_image)
background_img_view.addSubview(border)
background_img_view.addSubview(about_txt)
```

`about_txt` size is unknown, it can be 30px or 300px, now I want my `background_img_view`'s height to depend on `about_txt`'s height.

How can I make it happen programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the *sizeThatFits(_:)* method for the about_txt view. Use the size that this function returns and set the superview's size to that.
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622625-sizethatfits

If you have the subviews added before the view is on the screen, you could set the height in the *viewWillAppear* method of your view controller. You can also update the size in *viewWillLayoutSubviews*. 
If you're using auto layouts, have a look at [setNeedsLayout vs. setNeedsUpdateConstraints and layoutIfNeeded vs updateConstraintsIfNeeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609206/setneedslayout-vs-setneedsupdateconstraints-and-layoutifneeded-vs-updateconstra)

Comment: do you think i will learn anything about swift from apple's documentation? Could you please give an example of how to use sizeThatFits?