# Collection view Images Stuck in between

Tags: ios, swift3, uiscrollview, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

[image]

I have implemented a collectionView inside a collectionView Cell.
Lets name outer collectionView = collectionView(1) and collectionView inside cell = collectionView(2)
There are scrolling images in collectionView(2).

collectionView(1) will scroll vertically and collectionView(2) will scroll horizontally.

collectionView(2) functions are presented in collectionView(1) Cell file.

My problem is that when I scroll the collectionView(1), the images got stuck in between of collectionView(2)

The following code is inside CollectionViewCell File.

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.imagesCount
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HomePostImagesCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath)as! HomePostImagesCollectionViewCell
    cell.image.image = UIImage(named: "\((indexPath as NSIndexPath).item % imagesCount)")
    return cell
}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let vc = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:   "OpenPostViewController")as! OpenPostViewController
        let navigationController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
        navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)


    }
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: @Adeel i just updated the question with code

Comment: Your code seems to be okay. If you could share the `DataSource` of `collectionView1` and screenshots of the problem that may help find out why this is happening.

Comment: @Adeel I have uploaded the picture.The images stuck in between while scrolling otherwise its perfect. I think it is due to reusing of cells.

Comment: Your question states that the problem occurs when you scroll collectionView1. Need to see the `DataSource` of collectionView1 which you haven't shared yet.

Answer (score 2):

Hey I also  got this issue , I used

```
//Updation of screen
func layoutChange() {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    self.scrollView.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.scrollView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
}
```

or you can refer this link [setNeedsLayout vs. setNeedsUpdateConstraints and layoutIfNeeded vs updateConstraintsIfNeeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609206/setneedslayout-vs-setneedsupdateconstraints-and-layoutifneeded-vs-updateconstra)